# Como posso melhorar?

Tags: c

Comecei a aprender C faz alguns dias e criei esse programa, que de uma maneira simples calcula o salario de uma pessoa após receber alguns dados da mesma... Porem eu não trabalho na área de TI e não tenho ideia de como são os padrões usados no dia a dia entre os programadores, gostaria de pedir a vcs que me mostrassem o que no meu código esta fora desses padrões e como eu poderia deixar o código mais simples ou eficaz...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        float h, din, valorh, horasnormais, normal,
        extras, horas, inicio, resultado, minimo, turno, nivel;

        float base(float x, float y);
        float horaextra1(float x, float y, float z);
        float horaextra2(float x, float y);
        float inss(float z);
        float irrf(float z);
        float calcula_salario(float b, float h1, float h2, float ir, float ins, float insa, float a);
        float insalubridade(float minimo, float nivel);
        float adicional(float t, float valorh);

        minimo = 1045;
        system("cls || clear");

        printf("SISTEMA PARA CALCULAR SALARIO\n");
        printf("Digite a quantidade de horas trabalhadas: ");
        scanf("%f", &h);
        printf("Digite o valor da hora: ");
        scanf("%f", &valorh);
        printf("Qual o nível da insalubridade? ");
        scanf("%f", &nivel);
        printf("Qual o turno de trabalho? ");
        scanf("%f", &turno);

        if (h > 220 && h <= 242) {
                resultado = calcula_salario(base(h, valorh), horaextra1(h, valorh, base(h, valorh)),
                                         0, inss(base(h, valorh)), irrf(base(h, valorh)), insalubridade(minimo, nivel), adicional(turno, valorh));
                printf("O valor do salario é de: %.2f\n", resultado);
        }else if (h > 242) {
                inicio;
                resultado = calcula_salario(base(h, valorh), horaextra1(h, valorh, base(h, valorh)),
                                         horaextra2(h, valorh), inss(base(h, valorh)), irrf(base(h, valorh)), insalubridade(minimo, nivel), adicional(turno, valorh));
                printf("O valor do salário é de: %.2f\n", resultado);
        }else {
                normal = calcula_salario(base(h, valorh), 0, 0, inss(base(h, valorh)),
                                        irrf(base(h, valorh)), insalubridade(minimo, nivel), adicional(turno, valorh));
                printf("O valor do salário é de: %.2f\n", normal);
        }

        return 0;
}

float calcula_salario(float base, float extra1, float extra2, float inss, float irrf, float insa, float add) {
        float salario;
        salario = base + extra1 + extra2 - inss - irrf + insa + add;
        return salario;
}

float base(float x, float y){
        return x * y;
}

float horaextra1 (float x, float y, float z){
        float horasamais, valorextra, extra, salarioextra;
        horasamais = x - 220;
        extra = horasamais * 0.5;
        salarioextra = horasamais + extra * y;
        return salarioextra;
}

float horaextra2 (float x, float y) {
        float base, horasemdobro, valorextra, salarioemdobro, z;
        z = 33 * y;
        horasemdobro = x - 242;
        base = x - 22 * y;
        valorextra = horasemdobro * y;
        return valorextra;
}

float inss(float z){
        float valordesconto, diferenca;
        if(z <= 1045) {
                valordesconto = z * 0.075;
                return valordesconto;
        }else if(z <= 2089.60) {
                diferenca = z - 1045;
                valordesconto = diferenca * 0.09 + 78.37;
                return valordesconto;
        }else if(z <= 3134.41) {
                diferenca = z - 2089.60;
                valordesconto = diferenca * 0.12 + 78.37 + 94.01;
                return valordesconto;
        }else if(z >= 6104.06) {
                valordesconto = 713.08;
                return valordesconto;
        }else {
                printf("Algo deu errado inss\n");
        }

}

float irrf(float z) {
        if (z > 1903.99 && z <= 2826.66) {
                return z * 0.075 - 142.8;
        }else if(z > 2826.66 && z <= 3751.05) {
                return z * 0.15 - 354.8;
        }else if(z > 3751.05 && z <= 4664.68) {
                return z * 0.225 - 636.13;
        }else if(z > 4664.68) {
                return z * 0.275 - 869.36;
        }
}
float irrf(float z) {
        if (z > 1903.99 && z <= 2826.66) {
                return z * 0.075 - 142.8;
        }else if(z > 2826.66 && z <= 3751.05) {
                return z * 0.15 - 354.8;
        }else if(z > 3751.05 && z <= 4664.68) {
                return z * 0.225 - 636.13;
        }else if(z > 4664.68) {
                return z * 0.275 - 869.36;
        }
}

float insalubridade(float minimo, float nivel) {
        if (nivel == 1) {
                return minimo * 0.1;
        }else if(nivel == 2) {
                return minimo * 0.2;
        }else if(nivel == 3) {
                return minimo * 0.4;
        }
        else {
                printf("Insalubridade desconhecida\n");
        }
}

float adicional(float t, float valorh) {
        float horasnoturnas, valornoturno, adicional;
        if(t == 2) {
                printf("Horas trabalhadas por dia após 21h: ");
                scanf("%f", &horasnoturnas);
                valornoturno = valorh * 0.2;
                adicional = horasnoturnas * valornoturno;
                return adicional;
                }else if(t == 1) {
                        return adicional = 0;
                }else{
                        printf("Turno não reconhecido\n");
                }
}
´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

Algumas dicas para melhor seu código:

1 - a função *main*, responsável por executar um código, retorna um inteiro e não recebe nenhum parâmetro. Se a função não recebe nenhum parâmetro, o mais indicado é que você coloque a palavra *void* no espaço dos parâmetros. Apesar de parecer uma diferença pequena, alguns compiladores não compilam se você não fizer isso. Ficaria assim:

```
int main(void) {//resto do código}
```

2 - o seu código está bastante modularizado, este é um ponto positivo dele, parabéns. Você fez as assinaturas dos métodos dentro da função *main*. Geralmente, elas são feitas antes da função main. O objetivo da modularização (a divisão do código em várias funções) é tornar as funções o mais independentes possíveis entre si. Fazendo isso, você potencializa esse conceito dentro do seu código;

3 - pense sempre em usar nomes de variáveis que deixem o seu conteúdo o mais claro possível. Você fez isso para as variáveis dentro da função *main*, mas alguns parâmetros das funções não seguiram o mesmo padrão. Na função *irrf()*, por exemplo, fica difícil, para uma pessoa que está tendo o primeiro contato com o seu código, saber qual a utilidade da variável *z* dentro da função. Crie o hábito de utilizar nomes significativos de variáveis desde o seu começo na programação. A maioria dos códigos que você escreve serão lidos por outras pessoas ou por você mesmo no futuro. Ter esse hábito facilita esse futuro contato;

4 - em C, funções que retornam um determinado tipo de dados (ou seja, todas aquelas que não são *void*) precisam necessariamente retornar um valor ao fim da sua execução. Em algumas funções do seu código, como por exemplo no método *insalubridade*, caso o valor da variável *nível* não seja 1, 2 ou 3, você imprime uma mensagem de erro, mas não retorna nenhum valor. Por si só isso geraria uma mensagem de aviso na maioria dos compiladores e, durante a execução, geraria um erro. Quanto a isso, dois pontos:

- você deve checar se a variável passada para uma função está correta antes de chamar a função. Você poderia fazer isso através de estruturas condicionais dentro da função *main()*, antes de executar as funções;
- se você não quiser fazer isso, retorne na função um valor que indique erro, ou seja, um valor inválido dentro do contexto da função. Nesse caso, você poderia retornar o número -1. Se ao receber, na função *main()*, esse valor dessa função, você sabe que um erro ocorreu.

5 - o processamento que vocês dentro de algumas funções retornam valores específicos de acordo com os valores recebidos, como na função *irrf()*, em que o valor de retorno depende do valor da variável *z*, recebida por parâmetro. Quanto aos números usados dentro dos *ifs* e *elses*, evite colocar valores numéricos diretamente dentro do código. Em vez disso, use a diretiva *DEFINE*, que permite definir constantes identificadas por um certo nome. A sua aplicação é pequena, e isso não faria muita diferença. Mas imagine que você está desenvolvendo um programa grande, e que esses valores são utilizados em muitas funções diferentes. Se você precisa mudar o conteúdo deles, precisará mudar função por função, o que irá gerar um trabalho muito grande. Usando a diretiva *DEFINE*, mudando o valor da constante apenas uma vez o código inteiro será alterado. Além disso, será mais fácil para outros desenvolvedores (ou, como já foi dito, para você mesmo lendo seu código no futuro) entender ou lembrar qual o contexto desses valores dentro do código.

Ademais, para um iniciante o seu código está muito bom. Meus parabéns!